# StructType from Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**What I need to do?**

Create schema for a `DataFrame` that should look like this:

```
root
 |-- doubleColumn: double (nullable = false)
 |-- longColumn: long (nullable = false)
 |-- col0: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: double (nullable = true)
...
```

Columns with prefix `col` can vary in number. Their names are stored in an array `ar: Array[String]`.

**My attempt**

```
val schema = StructType(
    StructField("doubleColumn", DoubleType, false) ::
    StructField("longColumn", LongType, false) ::
    ar.map(item => StructField(item, DoubleType, true)) // how to reduce it?
    Nil
)
```

I have a problem with the commented line (4), I don't know, how to pass this array.

Comment: would having a case class like this help:
 case class MySchema(
                     doubleColumn:Double,
                     longColumn:Long,
                     ar:List[ArrayData]
                     )
  case class ArrayData(col:Double)

Comment: Is it really needed, if I'm only using it in this one place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to reduce anything. You can just perpend a list of known columns: val

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("doubleColumn", DoubleType, false),
    StructField("longColumn", LongType, false)
  ) ++ ar.map(item => StructField(item, DoubleType, true))
)
```

You might also

```
ar.foldLeft(StructType(Seq(
  StructField("doubleColumn", DoubleType, false), 
  StructField("longColumn", LongType, false)
)))((acc, name) => acc.add(name, DoubleType, true))
```